# "FFMPEG Binary Not Found" Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I installed moviepy package using pip. Whenever I import moviepy, the following error appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3137d113b348> in <module>()
      6 import os
      7 import math
----> 8 from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
      9 from IPython.display import HTML
     10 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py in <module>()
     20 # Clips
     21 
---> 22 from .video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
     23 from .video.io.ImageSequenceClip import ImageSequenceClip
     24 from .video.VideoClip import VideoClip, ImageClip, ColorClip, TextClip

C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py in <module>()
      1 import os
      2 
----> 3 from moviepy.video.VideoClip import VideoClip
      4 from moviepy.audio.io.AudioFileClip import AudioFileClip
      5 from moviepy.Clip import Clip

C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py in <module>()
     19 
     20 import moviepy.audio.io as aio
---> 21 from .io.ffmpeg_writer import ffmpeg_write_image, ffmpeg_write_video
     22 from .io.ffmpeg_reader import ffmpeg_read_image
     23 from .io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_merge_video_audio

C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py in <module>()
     17 from tqdm import tqdm
     18 
---> 19 from moviepy.conf import FFMPEG_BINARY
     20 from moviepy.tools import verbose_print
     21 

C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\conf.py in <module>()
     59         FFMPEG_BINARY = 'ffmpeg.exe'
     60     else:
---> 61         raise IOError("FFMPEG binary not found. Try installing MoviePy"
     62                       " manually and specify the path to the binary in"
     63                       " the file conf.py")

OSError: FFMPEG binary not found. Try installing MoviePy manually and specify the path to the binary in the file conf.py
```

I downloaded the FFMPEG file but I don't know to specify the path in conf.py.
Any help ?

Comment: you could add it your your system path, simple./

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, but in ubuntu. It got solved by simply installing ffmpeg using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when trying to use PythonVideoConverter

The steps I took to finally resolve this were:

pip install ffmpeg

Then you have to go download the ffmpeg executables separately.  Source code can be found here:

http://ffmpeg.org/

I actually used the pre-built binaries for windows available here:

https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases

The lines to use PythonVideoConverter are:

```
from converter import Converter

conv = Converter()
```

Add the absolute path to the executables as input parameters to Converter(), ie:

```
ffmpegPath = r"c:\...\ffmpeg.exe"

ffprobePath = r"c:\...\ffprobe.exe"

from converter import Converter

conv = Converter(ffmpegPath, ffprobePath)
```

edit: This was on Windows 10 using Python 3.7.4.  I used the win64-gpl build of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `anaconda` , but as per error dump

```
C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\conf.py in <module>()
     59         FFMPEG_BINARY = 'ffmpeg.exe'
     60     else:
---> 61         raise IOError("FFMPEG binary not found. Try installing
```

Here are steps that I can think of,

- Find out absolute path for `ffmpeg.exe` on your system.
- Copy that path.
- Edit `C:\Users\manch_000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\moviepy\conf.py`
- change line 59 to
  FFMPEG_BINARY = 'c:\your_path_to_ffmpeg.exeutable\ffmpeg.exe'
- save the `conf.py`

Hope this helps.

Comment: My issue was at `FFMPEG_BINARY`, I had to point the path the `ffmpeg.exe` file not the `bin` directory, although `FFMPEG_HOME` is already set to the `bin`.